# Webapp to split a map into sectors

Tags: images, collaboration, wikivoyage

## Context

At Wikivoyage we write articles about touristic destinations, for instance one article about [Manhattan Financial District](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Manhattan/Financial_District), one article about [Manhattan Chinatown](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Manhattan/Chinatown), etc. Areas often get rezoned, merged, split, moved, as article content changes.

So, we need a good way to collaboratively split the world into sectors, a bit like this:

[image: Wikivoyage sectors]

These limits are not official or anything: They are defined and modified all the time by Wikivoyage editors.

## Requirements

- Ability to move area points, split/merge areas
- Areas can contain sub-areas, for instance [Manhattan](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Manhattan) is inside [New york City](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/New_York_City)
- Ability to zoom: From continent to city neighbourhoods
- Data can be exported
- Collaboration à la Github: forking/pull requests or similar
- Anybody can fork and start modifying sectors, without having to wait for any approval
- Free
- Either hosted or run on our server

The software does not have to be map-specific, any software for splitting huge images into sectors is acceptable.